# Domo.js is trying to JSON.parse a png

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, domo

While developing a custom app for my organization, I am trying to request the name and the avatar of the individual accessing the card. I am able to get the name of the individual without any problems, but when requesting the avatar image I get the following console error:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid JSON response at XMLHttpRequest.d.onload (domo.ts:309:18)`

I have looked into the domo.js code, and after making some *limited* sense of things, I found that it tries to `JSON.parse` the `.png` that is returned.

When checking the network dev tools tab I can see the correct image getting returned, but it doesn't get passed to the app.

Here is the function that returns the error:

```
d.onload = function() {
                            var e;
                            if( u(d.status) ) {
                                !["csv","excel"].includes(r.format) && d.response || i(d.response), "blob" === r.responseType && i(new Blob([d.response], { type:d.getResponseHeader("content-type") }));
                                var t = d.response;
                                try{
                                    e = JSON.parse(t)
                                }
                                catch(e){
                                    return void c(Error("Invalid JSON response"))
                                }i(e)
                            }else c(Error(d.statusText))
                        }
```

As far as I can tell, `e` refers to the Domo environment, although I am not 100% sure of that.

*Note: I am turning to stackoverflow because my organization still has open support tickets with Domo that are more than 2 years old with no response, so I have little faith in getting a timely response from Domo regarding this issue.*

UPDATE: Here is the full function that is called-

```
function i(e,t,r,n,a) {
                    return r = r || {}, new Promise((function(i,c) {
                        var d = new XMLHttpRequest;
                        if (n?d.open(e,t,n):d.open(e,t), p(d,t,r), function(e,t) {
                            t.contentType ? 
                            "multipart" !== t.contentType && e.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", t.contentType)
                            : e.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", o.DataFormats.JSON)
                        } (d,r), function(e) {
                            s && e.setRequestHeader("X-DOMO-Ryuu-Token", s)
                        } (d), function(e,t) {
                            void 0 !== t.responseType && (e.responseType = t.responseType)
                        } (d,r), 
                        d.onload = function() {
                            var e;
                            if( u(d.status) ) {
                                !["csv","excel"].includes(r.format) && d.response || i(d.response), "blob" === r.responseType && i(new Blob([d.response], { type:d.getResponseHeader("content-type") }));
                                var t = d.response;
                                try{
                                    e = JSON.parse(t)
                                }
                                catch(e){
                                    return void c(Error("Invalid JSON response"))
                                }i(e)
                            }else c(Error(d.statusText))
                        },
                        d.onerror = function() {
                            c(Error("Network Error"))
                        }, a) 
                        if (r.contentType && r.contentType !== o.DataFormats.JSON) d.send(a);
                        else {
                            var f = JSON.stringify(a);
                            d.send(f)
                        }
                        else d.send()
                    }))
```

Here is the domo.js method that is being called to get the image:

```
e.get = function(e, t) {
                        return i(o.RequestMethods.GET, e, t)
                    },
```

Comment: What is `t` before `JSON.parse(t)` is called? `e` seems to refer to a few things here: the parsed response and an error .

Comment: well you have the code, I'd find this code in  your browsers devtools and set up a breakpoint to see if you get more specific, maybe also look at the call stack.

Comment: @user1599011 I have updated my post to include the full function and the `get` method defined by domo.js. And thank you!

Comment: @fnostro I will do that and update if I find out any more information that could be relevant. Thank you!

Comment: But what is t before JSON.parse(t) is called?

Comment: @user1599011 are you referring to where it is `var t = d.response`? Meaning that `t` is the response from the `XMLHttpRequest`, right?

Comment: Yes; what is its value? A string containing an image path?  JSON?

Comment: @user1599011 this is a piece of what is returned from `console.log`: `�PNG�9w�9j�Z�����֪��^�����16��*i��d��[k4�Z���Z3�J=hp��j>P��畟|^�ـ��V�U�T��`

Comment: This is before you called `JSON.parse(t)`? Is this the raw data? something doesn't seem quite right. What is `d.getResponseHeader("content-type")` and `r.format`?

Comment: `r.format` is an object, but it is empty. And it looks like `d.getResponseHeader("content-type")` is trying to get a nonexistent response header from the XMLHttpRequest. (It returns as `null`)

Comment: I may have figured out how to get it to work. This is really dumb, but all I had to do was set the query string to be the `<img>` source... You would think that would be in the documentation, but no. It was not. Thank you for your help @user1599011. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Skousini you can get the avatar for a user by providing this URL directly to the src property of the `<img>` tag (obviously replacing the query params with the relevant information):

```
<img src="/domo/avatars/v2/USER/846578099?size=300&defaultForeground=fff&defaultBackground=000&defaultText=D" />
```

This documentation is available on developer.domo.com: https://developer.domo.com/docs/dev-studio-references/user-api#User%20Avatar

If you want to pull down data from endpoints, you don't have to use `domo.js`. You could use axios or any other HTTP tool. `domo.js` is trying to make HTTP requests simpler by automatically parsing json (since most requests are json based). There are a few other options for what data format that `domo.get` can support provided in this documentation: https://developer.domo.com/docs/dev-studio-tools/domo-js#domo.get